# javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError running JBoss AS 7.1 with Java 7 update 171

Tags: java, jboss, nullpointerexception, compatibility

Upgrading Java from **7u161** to **7u171** prevents **JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final** from starting. I know JBoss AS 7.1.1 is EOL but for compatibility reasons, we still need to run this version.

Very early in the startup, a NullPointerException occurs in some JBoss method. Following is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider __redirected.__SAXParserFactory could not be instantiated: java.lang.NullPointerException
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:94)
```

The [full stack](https://gist.github.com/dleborgne/565dfe2adb80d441f9c30e9089734e6a) is here.

Comment: I have tested both Oracle JDK 7 Update 171 (Patch 27217226) and Oracle JDK 7 Update 171 b31 (Patch 27334355), with the same results.

Comment: This question was also asked in Oracle Community : https://community.oracle.com/message/14679602

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Could you try upgrading `jboss-modules.jar` (found in the root folder of the jboss-as binary distribution) to `1.1.5.GA`? 
The version of jboss-modules which comes with `jboss-7.1.1.Final` is `1.1.1.GA` and it has a few issues with initialisation order and multiple-initialisation which could be causing the issue.

Comment: Replacing the original jboss-modules.jar (1.1.1.GA) with [jboss-modules-1.1.5.GA.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/modules/jboss-modules/1.1.5.GA/jboss-modules-1.1.5.GA.jar) solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: download the jar file from here (  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjbossmodules115gajar.htm ) and rename it to jboss-module.jar and replace the original jar.

Answer (score 13):

Are you sure you are using a **jdk 1.7?**

This issue can happen when you try to start Jboss with **java version > 1.7,** try to check your JDK installation folder.

Comment: Spot on! Must check the JAVA_HOME in the environment variables too.

Comment: `OpenJDK 1.7.0_261` caused this, too.

Answer (score 6):

Environment as Follow:
Jboss: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final, 
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1, and,
java: 1.8.0_181.

I have downloaded [jboss-modules-1.1.5.GA.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/modules/jboss-modules/1.1.5.GA/jboss-modules-1.1.5.GA.jar)  and replace to jboss-modules.jar at JBOSS_HOME. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue on my Production Server

My Environment :-

```
JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final      
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5     
java: 1.7.0_181
```

Even i had jboss-modules.jar which comes by default in JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final ,
So i downloaded **jboss-modules-1.1.5.GA.jar** , renamed it as jboss-modules.jar
and replaced it with original jboss-modules.jar.