# Jboss 7 Server Not starting, nor showing error

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I have downloaded the 7.1.1.Final version of Jboss and I am trying to start the server as a standalone from command prompt(with JDK 1.8), but all I see is this below log for a more than 10minutes and even then my server is not spinning up.

Server start log:

```
Calling "D:\Server\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: D:\Server\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms1024M -Xmx4096M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

===============================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
12:30:20,643 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.5.GA
12:30:20,744 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
12:30:20,769 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

Previously I was getting a null pointer exception while starting the server so I replaced the jboss-modules.jar version from 1.1.1 to 1.1.5 as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48403832/javax-xml-parsers-factoryconfigurationerror-running-jboss-as-7-1-with-java-7-upd) and after that I am not getting the null pointer exception but I now my server not spinning up at all even for how long I wait.

Comment: I'm not sure JBoss AS 7.1.1 supports JDK 1.8. You should use WildFly (which replaced JBoss AS) instead.

Comment: I guess the problem was Jboss version. I am able to run with Wildfly 8.1 server. But is it really the jboss 7.1 version causing the server not spin? I expect at least it would throw some error then.

Comment: You should use WildFly 2. And if it might be the command line that is not working under Java 8, I'm not sure about that.